# Make a permanent exception for Steam's BuildBot in Windows 7 UAC

Tags: windows-7, security, uac, steam

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.
I am the only user of the computer, although I do have a password-protected backup account.
I have not disabled UAC, nor do I wish to.
I also use Steam (unfortunately).

The first time I run any newly-installed Steam game, I'm asked whether I wish to give the Steam BuildBot permission to modify my computer. The answer is *always* 'yes.'

I am growing really tired of going through this every single time. Surely, with Win7's "robust" permission system, there must be a way to permanently grant a given program elevated permissions such that no user is ever required to answer UAC-type questions when using that program, *without* disabling UAC or modifying the entire system.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

Oliver observes that I've misunderstood the facts of the situation.

So now, I'd like to know whether it's possible to add a permanent exception for programs signed by the Steam BuildBot, or -- more generally -- to make signature-based exceptions on a permanent basis without lowering other security settings on a system-wide basis.

Comment: There seems to be a slight misunderstanding. Steam is starting the setup executable of that game. This executable was [signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing) by the Steam BuildBot. I assume the build bot is an application that automatically constructs the setup for all Steam applications and then signs them. Windows will then ask you if you want to start the application and it will display the name of the entity that signed the executable :)

Answer (score 3):

UAC Can be set on a per application basis multiple ways. The other answers that say this is not true are wrong.

I don't know anything about BuildBot. But Programs can be set to admin mode  without needing UAC Prompt *and* without disabling or modifying UAC.

Most people choose Task Scheduler and do a shortcut bypass, meaning that using the new shortcut the program will start in Admin without UAC prompt. (But this may not be appropriate in this situation). Also it gives the option to start with windows.

Application Compatibility Toolkit [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352) from Microsoft is another option to try and doesn't need it to be run from a specific shortcut. It applies fixes governing the actual file (Like the compatibility options in properties). There is a Tut [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/selectively-disable-uac-for-your-trusted-vista-applications/635).

**EDIT:** I found another tutorial. It's a bit more up-to-date. http://meridian.ws/wordpress/?p=306

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, via the Steam Client Service. It was created specifically to allow it power access at all times (or so I understand). However you need to turn it ON via the control panel, select its properties and have it autostart on boot (not delay). My Win7 now boots Steam w/no UAC query. Only downside is most Steam apps will now also bypass UAC so this in a way leaves your system at risk, catch 22 eh? :)

Cheers, Eliot

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) would be even better if you provide a bit more detail on exactly how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are not and can not be given on a per-application basis, they are applied to
security principals (e.g. user accounts). So no, what you ask is not possible. You can,
however, adjust UAC settings so that administrator actions are automatically elevated
(i.e. no prompt). How is a single mouse click on a consent dialog reasonably describable
as "going through all this"?